# Shopify: I need a link to a product to place in a template file

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I need to add a link to a product in a template file. I was thinking of having in the schema a field the admin can edit. This field should be a select with all the products or a simple text field with autocomplete.

Is this possible? Or should I just have a simple text field and let admin copy/paste the actual product url in there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating settings in the theme, section or section-block, use 'product' as the field type. By choosing 'product' as the type, the merchant will be given a product-selector complete with a search box in the theme settings.  For all available field types, see https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema#special-input-setting-types

When you access the setting, you will be given just the handle of the product selected by the merchant.  If you named your setting 'user_product', you would translate that into an actual product object in Liquid using:

```
{% assign user_product = all_products[settings.user_product] %}
```

Since you have access to all of the attributes of the linked product, you can then place the URL of the selected product normally. Eg:

```
<a href="{{ user_product.url }}">{{ user_product.title }}</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note: you can only use `all_products` 20 times per page or it error.

Comment: @Buts: Aye - that is a point worth reiterating.  Any time that you're going to have a lot of products to look up, it's better to create a collection containing the products you need and then look up the collection instead.